# Privacy rules for setting user IDs with Google Analytics for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have an iOS app in which I'd like to use Google Analytics for Firebase to associate events with user IDs. The `setUserID` [method documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/FIRAnalytics#setuserid) states:

> Sets the user ID property. This feature must be used in accordance with Google’s Privacy Policy

But I am unsure exactly where in the Privacy Policy the rules are outlined. There is other information on the [Analytics support site](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) as well.

I am assuming that only non-identifiable user IDs are allowed, eg. a randomly generated, unique string for each user (`UID3515`). Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 2):

They are concerned with the collection of the Personally Identifiable information (PII).

Quoting from the docs:

***You will not, and will not assist or permit any third party to, pass information to Google that Google could use or recognize as personally identifiable information***

See the [Privacy](https://firebase.google.com/terms/analytics/#7_privacy) section in the Terms of Service for more details.

Comment: Just to clarify things: our backend generates an ID for every user that is used in the database to link resources to them (standard MySQL auto generated ID). If someone has this ID and access to the database, they can identify the individual users. Is this considered a PII? IMO it's okay to use this ID because Google has no access to it but I'm not sure and the legal language is just killing me.